# Was Buddha born of a Virgin?

Tags: the-buddha, history

I was reading a work that claims Buddha ["was born of the Virgin Maya"](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Page:The_Necessity_of_Atheism_%28Brooks%29.djvu/272). What Buddhist works address the birth of Buddha? Do any support or conflict with a virgin birth for Buddha?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This refers to a dream that Queen Maya had after trying for many years to have a baby with her husband. The reality is, they wrote that he was born to a woman who had been married for twenty years,

This Blog will help to clear your idea. http://www.rightreason.org/2009/the-virgin-birth-of-buddha/

Answer (score 8):

> Was Buddha born of a Virgin?

No. Tathagata Buddha was born as normal human being. He was named "Siddhartha Gautama". His birth is elaborated in some details over [here](http://www.columbia.edu/itc/mealac/pritchett/00ambedkar/ambedkar_buddha/01_1.html#03)

About the reference which you have given, the source from where you "got" this information - in my opinion this source is dangerous and is against Buddhist vision itself. It equates Krishna and Rama with Buddha! This is blunder. As I was Hindu (those who worship Krishna and Rama), I know that their message is nowhere close to Buddhist message. The whole things is conspiracy and in the Indian context it is called Brahminical conspiracy.

Answer (score 7):

As far as I know Queen Maya is not described as a virgin anywhere in the Pali canon, but she was believed to be sterile by most Burmese Buddhists. The account of the Buddha's birth is derived from Acchariyabbhuta dhamma Sutta of [Majjhima Nikaya](http://www.metta.lk/tipitaka/2Sutta-Pitaka/2Majjhima-Nikaya/Majjhima3/123-acchariyabbhutta-e.html)

Comment: the link in your answer is temporarily unavailable.

Comment: I've edit the link to the one that is working thanks

Answer (score 4):

Answer to the question "Was Buddha born of a Virgin?" **is No**

He was born as other normal humans are born into the world. Bodhisattva's who became Buddha in next immediate life are looking for 5 facts before they born into this world.

1. Suitable time
2. Suitable Land
3. Suitable Country
4. Suitable Cast
5. Suitable Mother

Here Mother should have various characteristics but here relevant factor is she should be **biologically available** (That means connection of Mother and Father as all of us know).

Load Buddha is not half god- half human but he has accepted him as a Normal human in lot of places. The Best location is **"Dhrona Sutta"** where Load Buddha has accepted he has born as a normal human.

As described in Dhrona Sutta, While Load Buddha was walking in between Udeni and Sawath towns, Load Buddha has met a Brahmin called Dhrona. Dhrona had seen special foot prints with various unusual symbols and marks and decided the owner of the foot prints cannot be a human and followed them.  Finally he has met Load Buddha at the end of footprint line and asked,

Are you a God?
Load Buddha said No.

then he asked following questions and got the same answer no. 
Are you a Devil?
Are you a Gandharwa (half god- half human)?
Are you a human?

Then he has asked as everyone of us would ask, then who you are?

Then Load Buddha has answered "Drona, I was born as a normal human, lived as a normal human but I have destroyed all the klesha (desires, lust and angry). So I am a extreme human. Most suitable name to identify me is "Buddha"".

And finally Sidhhartha Gauthaama became Load Buddha **not because of god has selected** him to be a Buddha, Instead he has **tried himself** continually for very very long time to become a Buddha in his previous lives with fullfilling generally 10 facts (descriptivly 30) called Paramitha.

Answer (score 0):

No, There is no truth of it .Buddha's fathe was king Suddhodana, leader of the Shakya clan and his mother was queen Maya Devi.So why there will raise a question of virgin birth of buddha ? He was born as all normal human born.

Answer (score 0):

The Dona sutta does not say that Buddha was a human being. It actually says the opposite, that he was not a human.

"No, brahman, I am not a human being."

The Pali canon does not explicitly say Maya was a 'virgin' but certainly implies that he was conceived without sexual intercourse. At any rate the canon very clearly indicates that the the Bodhisattva's birth was due to the volitional choice of the Bodhisattva, not the result of a biological function.